# Azure Media Service | Azure Storage Versioning in Project

Tags: c#, azure, azure-media-services

I have done Azure Media Services (AMS) POC.
but I am facing problem in integration of AMS into main project. Steps are below:

I am installing `windowsazure.mediaservices.extensions` package from NuGet but in this case

- it gives a error, **WindowsAzure.Storage** already has a dependency defined for 'NETStandard.Library`, because I have already installed WindowsAzure.Storage.8.1.0 package in project solution.
- If I removed this **WindowsAzure.Storage.8.0.0** then tried to install **windowsazure.mediaservices.extensions** package. it shows installation successful but version of WindowsAzure.Storage is 4.3.0 instead latest (8.1.0).
- If removing **WindowsAzure.Storage.4.3.0** forcefully and adding external reference of WindowsAzure.Storage.8.1.0 (Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll) then giving runtime error at the time of Creation of Asset on AMS.

Please suggest any solution.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried the same thing on one of the projects. It seems this is more of a Visual Studio or Nuget package manager update issue. I tried reproducing the same on a Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition and it worked. Check out the image below:

[image: You can see that the version for the AMS library is 3.8.0.3 and that of the storage library is 8.0.0. And the project builds successfully on my end.]